# Spring boot autowire and cross feature shared data

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, serenity-bdd, serenity-spring

As per the serenity BDD each scenario is solid

Serenity session variable will be lost for the second scenario

I am integrating SpringBoot using `@SpringBootTest`

My code is perfectly working whatever I wrote in the `Background` section of the feature file to call an URL, I wrote a piece of code to not to call the same service URL for the second time, rather it will take the data which is stored in a `HashMap` from an object which autowired using `@Autowired`

My Question is, is this against the BDD that one data gets maintained across more than one feature file or scenario

Answer (score 1):

Session data is reset for each scenario (by intent - scenarios are meant to be independent of each other). If you need to share data across multiple scenarios, you will need to implement this yourself.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I already did that, and I told that in that question itself, but my question is, is doing such coding against any testing principles ?